# event.preventDefault not working as it should

Tags: javascript, jquery

I loaded data using AJAX in a div.

```
<div id="container">
<a class="hello" href="abc.php">hello</a>   // loaded using ajax
<div>
```

Now I have jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.hello').on("click",function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 });
 });
 </script>
```

However it's not working as it should, i.e. it's directing me to `abc.php`. Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: what do you mean by always not working

Comment: its redirecting me to the page-> abc.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as your a tag is loaded dynamically

```
$('#container').on("click",".hello",function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) should be set up like this to work with dynamically created elements. Also, make sure to use Jquery version 1.8 or earlier versions.

Try:

```
$('#container').on("click",'.hello',function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Comment: while I am typing I haven't seen this answer. Hope we both are posted with some seconds difference.

Answer (score 0):

It also work from this..

```
$('.hello').click(function(){
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: will not work OP loaded the a tag using ajax so .a tag is not the part of dom at page load time.